# Unknown Entity Error With ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, crud

OK, so I've designed a basic CRUD an an exercise.  It has 2 tables Jobs and Employees.  I'm trying to create a many to one relationship, but when I click the link to go to the Employee Entry page it throws an error that kicks off with the @ManyToOne referencing an Unknown Entity.

Here is what I've got in my Employees.java

```
String jobName;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "Job_Name")
@Column (name='jobName')
public String getJobName() {
return jobName;
}

public void setJobName(String jobName) {
this.jobName = jobName;
}
```

Any idea what i"m doing wrong and how to resolve this?

Comment: post your Employee and Job entity both?,for the moment your @ManyToOne relationship in incorrect.

Comment: I can't post them, as it's a separate work computer that I'm using.  You mentioned it being incorrect, how should I go about?

Comment: is this @ManytoOne relationship between Employee and Job?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to have many employees having one job name. The job name has to be included in the Employee table, and then I have to add a field to the .jsp for it so it can be entered with employee information.

Comment: I've looked at an absurd amount of documentation, as I've never done these sort of relationships via annotation, and I still can't get it.

Comment: just added answer,have a look and try to implement in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment,i think you can define relationship between these two entities like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
class Employee{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "job_name")
  private Job job;

 // other column and getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name="job")
class Job{

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private Integer id;

      @Column(name="job_name")
      private String jobName;

      //provide other column and getter setter

}
```

Comment: i was told that the @ManyToOne had to be attached to the getter for the column.

So please allow me to confirm

I add this...

Comment: @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "job_name")
  private Job job;

Do I then add specific getter and setters for the foreign field like I did previously, or do I let it go like this.

Comment: i agree with your first statement you can add @ManyToOne to getter also,but give a try to as i did,and yes you will have to write setter and getter for job field in Employee class